# キーボードショートカットの登録方法

Tags: emeditor

コマンドやマクロをキーボードショートカットに登録する方法を教えて下さい。
＜例＞
CSVモードで[マクロ] ツール バーの Σ (合計) ボタンをクリックする代わりにキーボードで合計を求めたい。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コマンド (マイ マクロに登録されているマクロを含む) を好きなキーボード ショートカットに設定するには、次のようにします。

1. [ヘルプ] メニューの [キーボード マップ] を選択します (ここで、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> を押して [クイック起動] にしても、以降、ほとんど同じ操作です)。
2. もしショートカットをどの設定でも共通に変更したい場合には、ツール バーの [キーマップの設定] を選択して表示されるメニューで、[すべての設定] にチェック マークが設定されている状態にします。反対に、現在表示中の設定 (EmEditor 起動直後だと、通常「Text の設定」) だけを変更したい場合は、[すべての設定] にチェック マークが設定されていない状態にします。

[image: EmEditor キーボード マップ - すべての設定]

3. [検索] ボックスで、設定したコマンド名 (またはマクロのファイル名) の一部を入力します。例えば、合計マクロの場合、「sum」と入力します。すると、入力した文字列に一致したコマンドが一覧に表示されます。

[image: EmEditor キーボード マップ - 検索]

4. 変更したいコマンドの 1つを選択して、ツール バーの [キーボードのプロパティ] ボタンをクリックします。
5. 設定のプロパティの [キーボード] ページが表示されるので、変更したいコマンドが選択されていることを確認して、[追加するショートカット キー] に設定したいショートカットを入力します。

[image: EmEditor 設定のプロパティのキーボード ページ]

6. [割り当て] ボタンをクリックして、OK ボタンをクリックします。

Comment: 説明どおり設定できました。
とても便利です。